# how can we setup a specific github repository in TabbyML for Repository context for code completion

Tags: autocode

is tabby scheduler or tabby scheduler --now a command and if so how to execute it

Set up the TabbyMl for autoCompletion of code but not giving autocompletion from a specific github repo even after specifying the repo name in config.toml